# a function that returns a procedure in scheme

Tags: scheme

You are required to define a function (lets say add-y) of one argument y that returns a procedure which takes one argument x  and returns the summation of both arguments ie y and x. Using the the defined function add-y, write a procedure mul that takes two integer arguments d and e and returns their product

Comment: i.e. "Do my homework for me."

Comment: "Whaaaat... is the air-speed velocity of a flying grue?"

Answer (score 3):

```
(define (add-y y)
  (lambda (x) (+ x y)))

(define add-5 (add-y 5)) 

(add-5 2)
```

result : 7

Comment: When the question is homework, it's better to guide them to the solution than to outright give it. While they get an answer (and you get your rep) they _learn nothing_.

Comment: At the very least you should explain the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (add-y y) (lambda (x) (+ x y)))

(define (mul d e)
 (if (= e 0)
     0
     ((add-y d) (mul d (- e 1)))))
```

Comment: When the question is homework, it's better to guide them to the solution than to outright give it. While they get an answer (and you get your rep) they _learn nothing_.

Comment: @Paul, personally i dont think people should be posting homework questions here unless theyve given it a real shot themselves. such a person would then post what they tried and/or what they didn't understand, to which the community could helpfully respond. this post has none of those signs. you can only help those who help themselves...

Comment: Then instead of promoting this behavior, you should not provide an answer and comment on _why_ you have not provided an answer. If they still insist on not putting any effort into it, then still don't answer. I know I won't; I don't want someone like that graduating as I might actually _have to work with them_ in the future. Scary.

Comment: @Paul: realistically, if stackoverflow doesnt provide a solution, then a friend or asking elsewhere will. im not his mother, and have no intention of trying to teach him the virtue of putting in an effort. as such, if he displays an unwillingness to make an effort i would prefer to make his life as simple as possible, thereby minimising his understanding of the material and maximising his likelihood to fail the final exam thereby minimising the likelihood i will ever have to work with him.

Comment: And yet somehow someone somewhere is capable of benefitting from this knowledge in the manner in which davin has described.